# CSS/HTML - How to set inner padding inside input?

Tags: input, textbox, padding

When I try to set a padding it's not center anymore. It moves to the other side.

How can I set padding of the textbox input so that it's still aligned center?

```css
table {
  text-align: right;
}
#textfield {
  float: left;
}
.textbox { 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.44); 
  color: #333; 
  border: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
  padding-left: 5px;
  line-height: 1; 
  width: 225px; 
  height: 18px;
  border-spacing: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table width="450" border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="225"><label>First Name:</label></td>
      <td width="225">
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Oriol! Can you contribute a possible solution as well?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, for me it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 17):

You can try adding

```css
.textbox { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
table {
  text-align: right;
}
#textfield {
  float: left;
}
.textbox { 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.44); 
  color: #333; 
  border: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
  padding-left: 5px;
  line-height: 1; 
  width: 225px; 
  height: 18px;
  border-spacing: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table width="450" border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="225"><label>First Name:</label></td>
      <td width="225">
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```